# JSTL version to be used with JSF 2.1

Tags: java, jsf-2, jstl

i want to know what version of JSTL to be used with JSF 2.1 on tomcat 7
please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab JSTL 1.2. A download link can be found in [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (which you can access yourself by putting your mouse above the [jstl](/questions/tagged/jstl) tag below your question and then clicking the *info* link in the popbox).

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 already has the jstl 1.2 embedded. So you don't need anything more. If your project is managed by maven, you can add java.sevlet:jstl as provided.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't ship with JSTL.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I tought it did. I must have mixed it with jetty.